# What does this error means on a Flash banner?

Tags: flash, actionscript, banner

I get the following error

[ImageError - Reason: FLASH_HAS_RANDOM_NUM, Field Path = operations[0].operand.ad.image.data]

Any ideas what that means?

The only random call I have is to get a random 360 angle for a set of particles, and the code is at the end of a movieclip within other movieclips

Thanks

UPDATE:
I am using Flash CS3 and the banner settings are: Flash 8 and AS2,

The code for the random bit is `this._rotation = Math.random() * 360;`

Comment: Haven't met this error. Is it AS3 you are doing or AS2? Are you using the Flash IDE or something else? Can you put your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error generated by Google Ads, certainly to prevent the banner from having an unpredictable behavior. Thus you can't use Math.random() in a banner...